# How to properly annotate pydantic fields if it's another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I have a model with the fields which are other Pydantic models (but not instances of them), so I'm able to use it later as a builder.

```py
class ItemModel(BaseModel):
    id: int

class UserModel(BaseModel):
    name: str

class MatchModels(BaseModel):
    name: str
    user_model: Optional[type(BaseModel)] = None
    item_model: Optional[type(BaseModel)] = None


m = MatchModels(
    name="match only user",
    user_model=UserModel,
)
```

Is it correct to use `type(BaseModel)` here if I want to instantiate it later somewhere in the code? What is the proper type annotation would be here?

Comment: Can `user_model` be anything different than `UserModel`? I'd just use `type` as a type. If you want to be more precise, use [`ModelMetaclass`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py#L59)

Comment: Where do you actually create the instance of `UserModel`?

Comment: I am not 100% sure wat you would like to achieve, but I am convinced that setting the type as a configurable field is not the right approach. Depending on your use case this either sounds like using a generic type or a discriminated union might the better approach. It would be good to provide some more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) suggest to annotate like this

```py
from typing import Optional, Type

class MatchModels(BaseModel):
    name: str
    user_model: Optional[Type[BaseModel] = None
    item_model: Optional[Type[BaseModel]] = None
```